# переменные в bat файлах

Tags: cmd, bat

Пишу скрипт,который бы принимал первым параметром путь к папке и копировал ее содержимое в другую,заданную потом.Есть командные символы для первого параметра, это "/?" по которому выводится краткая информация о задаче,проверка на существование и собственно часть кода,где разбирается путь,если он существует и введен правильно.

```
@echo off
echo *****************************************
echo *  Копирование файлов в заданную папку  *
echo ***************************************** 
setlocal
set flag = false

if "%1%" EQU "" (
    set flag = true

    echo Не задан основной параметр. Введите /? для справки
    )

if "%1%" EQU "/?" (
    set flag = true
    echo командный файл копирования файлов заданного типа с помощью команды copy_   из одной папки в другую. 
    echo В качестве первого обязательного параметра должно быть задано имя исходной папки 
    echo для текущей папки задается символ ".". Вторым необязательным параметром является тип файла
    echo image – для файлов изображений с расширениями .bmp , .gif, .jpg и .png
    echo prog – для программных файлов с расширениями .com и .exe
    echo text – для текстовых файлов с расширениями .doc и .txt
    echo all – для всех файлов.
    echo Если второй параметр не задан, для него предполагается значение all. 
    echo В командном файле выдается запрос на ввод имени папки, в которую будут копироваться файлы
    echo для текущей папки задается символ "." Имена исходной папки и папки, в которую будет производиться копирование
    echo не должны совпадать. Если папка с заданным именем не существует, она создается с помощью команды mkdir.
    echo Для значений параметров image, prog или text должно быть выведено общее количество 
    echo скопированных файлов соответствующего типа изображений, программных или текстовых
    )

 if %1 NEQ . (
    echo "%flag%"
    if "%flag%" EQU "false" (
        if exist "%1%" (
            echo Путь существует и не равен командным символам
        )else (
            echo Путь не существует
            )
        )
)


endlocal
```

Переменную флага ввел для того,что бы при строке типа "/?" и пустой строке,интерпретатор не заходил в `if %1 NEQ . (....)`
Но при исполнении этого кода получаю ошибку:"Непредвиденное появление: ..",а переменная flag вообще ничего не содержит.
Подскажите,что делаю не так.Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В итоге,первая ошибка:

```
set flag = false
```

так, как по сути переменная,это макрос, то после равно он видит пробел и присваивает его переменной. Нужно

```
set flag=false
```

Вторая ошибка

```
if %1 NEQ . (
```

он почему то ругается на непредвиденное появление ..
решил так:`if "%1" NEQ "." (`